# Biblatex and authoryear not working as expected

Tags: biblatex

I'm using `MikTex 2.9.5105` with `TeXnicCenter 2.02 Stable` and have no to basic knowledge of LaTeX.

I want my citations to have the form

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet (Kosiol 1961, S. 319) consectetuer
>   adipiscing elit Kosiol (1961).

**In the preamble**

```
\usepackage[
    style=authoryear,
    isbn=false
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{EndfassungLiteraturDatenbank.bib}

...

\printbibliography
```

**In the .bib**

```
@Article{Kosiol1961,
  Title                    = {Modellanalyse als Grundlage unternehmerischer Entscheidungen},
  Author                   = {Kosiol, E.},
  Journal                  = {ZfbF 13},
  Year                     = {1961},
  Pages                    = {318-334},

  Owner                    = {Karl},
  Timestamp                = {2015.04.09}
}
```

**In the text**

```
\parencite[319]{Kosiol1961} --> expecting "(Kosiol 1961, S. 319)"
\textcite[319]{Kosiol1961} --> expecting "Kosiol (1961, S. 319)"
```

**Current output after 4 times of compilation**

```
\parencite[319]{Kosiol1961} --> (Kosiol1961)
\textcite[319]{Kosiol1961} --> Kosiol1961
```

The bibliography is not printed at all.

Comment: Welcome, apparently you speak german. https://github.com/johannesbottcher/HinweiseLitverzeichnisse/blob/master/Hinweise.md#troubleshooting

Comment: You have to run Biber

Comment: If the outputted stuff is in bold face, please read from the beginning.

Comment: Thanks for your great support. I solved the problem within a minute :)

Comment: @Johannes_B: it is no longer true that one has to install biber manually in miktex 64bit, a package has been added.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You are right, i'll change it.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of the stock [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864), then.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

Thanks to Johannes_B and his brilliant github site https://github.com/johannesbottcher/HinweiseLitverzeichnisse/blob/master/Hinweise.md#troubleshooting I managed to achieve my desired citations and bibliography.

1. I had to put biber.exe, a replacement for the bibtex.exe, in `MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\`
2. I had to change one line in my output profile in TexnicCenter: ALT + F7 opens the profiles dialog. There you set the path to the BibTex-compiler. Replace bibtex.exe with biber.exe
3. Compile the document several times with CTRL + F5